# Missing swf plugin in Google Chrome [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, plugins, swf

How to play .swf file in Google Chrome? Because when I open .swf files it says `Missing Plug-in.`  though when I open `chrome://plugins` it shows that it has `Shockwave Flash` plugin installed already.
My OS is Ubuntu 10 and would be happy if some linux geek could suggest me solution of my problem.

Thanks and sorry for stupid question. 

**Update 1** 
Here is information about version of the applications I use:

- Chrome 5.0.375.70 (48679) Ubuntu
- Shockwave Flash 9.0 r999

**Update 2**
I have solved the problem by the following way:

- Opened Application Manager Synaptic
- Deleted all the packages concerning flash and swf
- Opened up Application Center Ubuntu
- Searched for flash
- It found Adobe Flash Plugin
- Installed that application

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and mark it as correct so this question is marked as solved. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by the following way:

- Opened Application Manager Synaptic
- Deleted all the packages concerning flash and swf
- Opened up Application Center Ubuntu
- Searched for flash
- It found Adobe Flash Plugin
- Installed that application

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Failing that, what is the precise version and package of your chrome installation and what is the detailed flash information from chrome://plugins?

Comment: see updated part of the question

Comment: getting error while trying to execute your command in the terminal.

Comment: ok, what sort of error?

Comment: Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo aptitude reinstall flashplugin32-installer`

Note: replace the 32 with 64 if you are running a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Error. Could not find packages containing «flashplugin64-installer» on their name or description.What is wrong?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?